# Calculate the power in a bow string using matlab

Tags: matlab, physics

I'm trying to calculate the force in a bow string while using `MATLAB`'s `ode45`, I have this differential equation

```
M(x)=d^2y/dx^2 * (1+(dy/dx)^2)^(-3/2)=-q * y where M(x) is the average torque in the bow, q=11.4716, and y(0)=0.3, y'(0)=0 and 0≤ x ≤0.3668
```

I have calculated the differential equation with ode45 but I have tried to calculate the force with this code;

```
X=0.3668
tolerance=odeset('Abstol', 1e-9, 'Reltol', 1e-11);
[x,M]=diffekv45(tolerance,X)    

force=zeros(length(x),1);
for i=1:length(x)
    if x(i)==0
        force(i)=0;
    else
        force(i)=(0.3-M(i,1))./x(i); %%% 0.3-M(i,1) is because it is equilibrium in the         %%center of the bow
    end
end
totalforce=sum(force);
```

Line 6 is calculating the torque in all the readings. I suppose that the first element in M is the average torque.

I'm using these functions

```
function [x,M] = diffekv45(tolerance,X)
    u0=[0.3;0];
    [x,u]=ode45('M',[0,X],u0,tolerance);
end

function M=M(~,u)
global q 
    M=[u(2)
        -q*u(1)*(1+u(2)^2)^(3/2)];
end
```

When I calculate the force with a higher or lower tolerans I get a significant higher or lower value of the force. That's why I'm wrong. So how can I calculate the force in the bow string?

Comment: Isn't this basically a question about the underlying physics? You tagged it "matlab" only.

Comment: You shouldn't need an integrator to calculate forces. Force come from the elastic properties and geometry. The integrator is used to calculate deflections in a transient fashion. Please clarify if you want a steady state solution, a harmonic solution or a transient solution and post into [Physics.SE] first to get the equations correct before trying to code it. Can you add a reference of where you are getting these equations?

Comment: I got the equations from transforming the second order differential equation to two first order differential equation where y=u(1),y'=u(2), u(1)'=y'=u(2). And for the equation that calculates the force I just took a chance. So it´s wrong to use ode45? Thank you

Comment: The function `M` above should return `M=[u(2); -q*u(1)/(1+u(2)^2)^(3/2)];`

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it belongs to [Physics.SE] in order to get the proper force function **before** any code is written.

Answer (score 0):

You have a 2nd order equation in terms of the displacement, which needs to be split up into two first order equations for use in `orde45()`.

Use a state vector `h=[y; diff(y,x)]` and create the following differential function for use in `ode45()`

```
function hp = deriv(x,h)
  y = h(1);       %First element of h is the deflection
  v = h(2);       %Last element of h is the slope
  hp = [v; -q*y/(1+v^2)^(-3/2)];
end
```

and then call

```
h0 = [0.3; 0];
ode45(deriv, [0,X], h0, tol);
```

Comment: Exactly and I have created the differential function but I have a problem creating h=[y; diff(y,x)] I don't know y, should i get it from another ode45?

Comment: I am experiencing the same problem as before, higher/lower tol = higher/lower force, and I don't know the function of y. In previous assignment I have calculate the arc length and have got the values of y but not the function so I can't derivate in h=[y,diff(y,x)].